# JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: exception, jboss, classnotfoundexception

I'm developing in spring MVC model.
when I start jboss server, it makes error. But I have no idea about that. 
Because when I run server in other projects, I don't see any errors.

```
10:38:17,879 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/CustomerService]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 104) JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: tps.fbbs.cutomer.CustomerName
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:190) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:89) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:256) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:113) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveAlias(BaseBuilder.java:130) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:101) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:72) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:135) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:128) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:118) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:92) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:464) [mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:340) [mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

already I followed some answers, but nothing to happen.
also I checked 'eployement assembly in properties' but there's nothing...

Comment: Is the class `tps.fbbs.cutomer.CustomerName` in your classpath?

Comment: yes..  @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

Answer (score 0):

This is the error `Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: tps.fbbs.cutomer.CustomerName
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:190) [mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]`

Make sure you have this .class file in WEB-INF\

Else as .jar under WEB-INF\lib\

classpath is nothing to do with .war (Web Archive). Should be placed under `WEB-INF`

I hope this helps.

I presumed it is web archive as shown error is appropriate to `servlet`

I had similar error with same error code `JBWEB000289`. In my case ActiveMQ service was anticipated running on a particular port.

Comment: One of colleague from my last company did something for not placing EJB .jar project or classes under `WEB-INF`. He basically tweaked the nature to build project in Eclipse environment itself as .ear wherein as I say he doesn't physically place the .class files under `WEB-INF`. Let me explore that possibility and tell you once I found that another way.

Comment: He basically done some `buildcommand` addition/alteration under `.settings` (folder) of eclipse project. So we can directly build the ear using eclipse build itself.